# Can we have multiple h1 tags and make them smaller in size than other header?

Tags: html, html-heading

I have a homepage with slider after the header. Below the slider are other content sections.

I am not sure how to structure my document. Where should I place my `h1` and can I have multiple `h1` tags?

Is it good practice to use `h1` tags for banner captions or banner titles?

The problem is that some designs make it hard to document the structure properly.

```
<body>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slide">
            //some text - image in background
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            //some text - image in background
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
             //some text - image in background
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="client-wrapper">
        <h2>Our Clients</h2>
        <div>
          Client Logos
        </div>
  </div>
  ....
</body>
```

Comment: Your document should have one and only one `<h1>` element. `<h2>` onwards you can have multiple of.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - can you suggest what should be my h1 tag on the above homepage I mentioned

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol not so in HTML5, see https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824

Comment: Can you please include the header, too? For answering where/which headings should be used, we need to see the whole structure of the document.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally possible to have many `h1` tag, but structurically it may be better if you have only one `h1`. You can modify your headers `h1`'s `font-size` with CSS if you have it inside something, like `header` tag. Like that:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1>My awesome page!</h1>
</header>
<h1>Thing I want to talk about today</h1>
```

CSS:

```
header h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **requirement** that you only have 1 h1 tag ([see the example in the WHATWG doc here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements)), but many designers reserve h1 to the title of the page, useing lower-level headers sub-headings. I would recommend only putting one on the page.

h2,h3,etc. will, by default, be smaller than h1. While you could use multiple h1 tags with class attributes to target CSS to the different headers, I would highly discourage this, use **h2,h3,etc instead**.

I'm not clear on what exactly you mean by "banner headers/captions" in this context.

Comment: I've added some code to make the HTML structure clear

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I place my `<h1>`?

The `<h1>` element is generally used to mark up the primary heading of the document, so... the `<h1>` element will conventionally appear somewhere near the top of the visually-displayed document.

In the source mark-up, you can technically place the `<h1>` anywhere, since `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` in your **CSS** will be sufficient to display the element somewhere near the top of the visual document.

Normally however `<h1>` appears in the source mark-up quite soon after the `<body>` begins.

> Can I have multiple h1 tags.

Something of a hornet's nest. *Yes* you can, ***but***...

It's probably inadvisable.

The best single article which looks how document structure and headings *were intended* to work in HTML5 and how everything *actually works* in practice is:

[The HTML5 Document Outline is a dangerous fiction](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/) by *Steve Faulkner*

> Is it good practice to use h1 tags for banner captions or banner
>   titles?

It's good to use `h-something` elements for all sorts of headings and heading-like elements throughout your document.
Bear in mind though that some elements have their own native caption elements.

- `<figure>` uses `<figcaption>`
- `<table>` uses `<caption>`

Answer (score -1):

This is a good post. As a UX/UI guy I run into issues where different pages need different H1-H3. To keep the style guide organized I have H1 but labeled large/medium/small